# Get current branch name

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I'm running a script (bitbucket_pipelines.yml) and on one of the steps I need to know the current branch name, How can I get it?

I saw there is a predefined `BITBUCKET_BRANCH` variable, but I'm having troubles to print it so I can see its content.

I tried to do:

```
...
step:
  script: 
    - echo $BITBUCKET_BRANCH
```

but when pipelines runs all I see is

`echo $BITBUCKET_BRANCH`

How can I really see the content of this variable?

Answer (score 3):

I found that Bb Pipelines are sometimes picky when dealing with variables. Try changing this to `echo "$BITBUCKET_BRANCH"`. Also, enclosing the *whole line* in single quotes might help.

Answer (score 0):

@Shvalb, the question should be how to display the value of a variable in bitbucket pipeline.

I deal with bitbucket support on this matter before.
I want to echo a repo/pipeline variable to see the value and it is not showing correctly.

In my case, it was my repo variable conflict with my deployment/pipeline variable. However, from the support, I understand bitbucket is using search and replace the screen value to "hide" the actual value of the variable with direct echo.

in order to see the value, you can use

echo $VAR > /tmpfile
cat /tmpfile

It was the trick I used before but I am not sure whether it will still work.